# Cross-validation over rolling fit

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

Is there a way to perform cross-validation obeying the time ordering of data in a problem where we are learning over a rolling fit - e.g. when fitting a predictive model in the history of football matches - so as to not use future examples in the parameter selection part of the training?

Comment: I don't understant your setup. Do you want to cross validate within each window? Then the fact that you have a rolling window does not matter because you can take one window at a time. If not, then taking rolling windows is itself a form of cross validation if you train on a window and test on a subsequent period.